Generating function for dimensions of the space of polynomials fixed by a single permutation
Consider the space of polynomials with complex coefficients $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ and let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$ that acts on
this space via $\sigma(x_i)=x_{\sigma(i)}$. Is there a nice generating function for the dimension of the degree $d$ fixed point subspace?
My guess: consider the cycle decomposition of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with respect to $\sigma$, viewed as orbits for the subgroup of the symmetric group generated by $\sigma$. Call this set of orbits $\mathcal{O}$
Let $\ell$ be the lcm of the sizes of the orbits in $\mathcal{O}$, and for $O\in \mathcal{O}$, let $\omega_{|O|}$ denote the $|O|$-th primitive root of unity. For reasons I can provide justification for if needed, I believe the generating function will be:
$$\frac{1}{\ell}\sum\limits^{\ell-1}_{k=0} \prod\limits_{O\in \mathcal{O}}\prod\limits^{|O|-1}_{i,j=0} \frac{1}{1-\omega^{ijk}_{|O|}z^j}$$
(the sum is related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981996/generating-functions-for-partitions-of-n-with-an-even-number-of-parts-and-odd-nu)
But even if this is right, I would really appreciate a reference to avoid having to prove it!
Thank you

You might look at Richard Stanley's paper Invariants of finite groups and their applications to combinatorics, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 1(3): 475-511 (1979), https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-03/S0273-0979-1979-14597-X/

This calculation can be done using Molien's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molien%27s_formula

So it is, thank you again!
